# Resumable upload error 401

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I carefully tested big files resumable upload.

Briefly results are the following:

**Scenario 1**

1. Obtain an access token.
2. Start uploading.
3. While access token not expired, you can stop the upload and resume it again as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable) with no problem, (even if I request a new access token, during the period initial access token has not expired (one which began uploading), so with this new access token I can continue uploading, **BUT** again *only during the period initial access token has not expired*).

**Scenario 2**

1. Obtain access token.
2. Start uploading.
3. Access token expired.
4. Obtain a new access token using the refresh token.
5. Continue uplolading.
6. Received a **401** error **WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm ="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest ", error = invalid_token** - error occurs **ALWAYS** while there are steps 3 and 4.

**Conclusion:** since access token is valid for one hour, you can not upload a big file (in case of the upload time of this file exceeds 1 hour, for example, or access token has expired while you uploading the file).

**Questions:**

*Is this conclusion right?*

*Why?*

*Is this the Google Drive error and really I can not upload a big file as described above?*

Thanks.

Comment: this question has been asked many times, each time without a response.

Comment: Interesting to know why there is no response from the Google Drive Team?

Comment: We have a bug for this and are working on towards a solution.

Comment: **Dear Mr. Dan McGrath**,

what is the status of this bug at the current moment?

Thanks.

Comment: This bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=231) has been present for more than a year. Our workaround is to just use the [old API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) for big files (that's what the Google Drive client uses anyway).

Comment: I'll try it, thank you. Nevertheless, as this approach is out of date and officially deprecated, I'm waiting for a message from Google here when this bug will be fixed. Thousands of services all over the world use Google Drive and have to use this bug... but Google Drive developers can not fix this issue ~1.5 years, I am very surprised. In this thread have answered Mr. Dan @McGrath who is Google Drive Product Manager, I hope he will explain why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a small example Java code which can upload big files (tested > 30G) and put it on GitHub: https://github.com/dirkboye/GDriveUpload
The app can switch between old and new API to aloow for uploads lasting longer than hour.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is right. You can’t upload big files yet. Although Google Drive developers say they are trying to fix this bug, it’s not known when their job will be finished. Meanwhile, I would advise simple alternative=DropBox+Mediafire. DropBox allows resumable upload. Big file (less than 2 GB) can be uploaded on DropBox, then it can be transferred to MediaFire with method “add_web_upload”.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your advice but DropBox+Mediafire is impossible for me.
I hope Google Drive developers should fix this critical and serious bug in the nearest future.