# Refresh token in Google Drive (OAuth2) in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a python script to upload large file into Google Drive.
When passes one hour after the start of the script I get the error:
**"Refreshing due to a 401
Refreshing access_token"**
And script exit with error:

```
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1291, in _conn_request
response = conn.getresponse()
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1067, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''*
```

How to update the token during loading without interrupting it?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789284/resumable-upload-error-401 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286402/google-drive-python-api-resumable-upload-error-401-after-2-hours (and probably a few others too)

Comment: How could such large corporation like Google may not be fixed a bug more than a year ?!

Answer (score 0):

As of initial posting, this was a bug in our stack. The team has been working to address it.

**Good news** - this bug has now been fixed. Please try again and confirm. You shouldn't need to do anything else during your upload, even if it takes over 1 hour.

Comment: YES! It work! Now i uploading more the 6 hour and now not have error!
File still uploading. When finished, i tell you results. Thank YOU!